# Parameter issue on Dart

Tags: dart

can somebody explain why

```
class SaveGlove {
final String serialNumber;
final String productionDate;

SaveGlove(this.serialNumber, this.productionDate);

SaveGlove.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
    : this(
      serialNumber: json['serialNumber']! as String,
      productionDate: json['prductionDate']! as String,
    );

Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
return {
  'serialNumber': serialNumber,
  'prductionDate': productionDate,
};
}
}
```

doesn't work but when I change parameter in constructor like that:

```
  SaveGlove({required this.serialNumber, required this.productionDate});
```

it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code doesn't work because your constructor is declared to take two *positional* arguments,

```dart
SaveGlove(this.serialNumber, this.productionDate);
```

but you are calling it with *named* arguments:

```dart
    : this(
      serialNumber: json['serialNumber']! as String,
      productionDate: json['prductionDate']! as String,
    );
```

(This is a redirecting generative constructor, which tries to redirect to the `SaveGlove` constructor by passing it two named arguments.)

That doesn't work, positional parameters need positional arguments.
If you had written the redirecting constructor as:

```dart
    : this(
      json['serialNumber']! as String,
      json['prductionDate']! as String,
    );
```

then it would have worked.

Changing the constructor to take two named parameters also makes the redirection be valid.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Null Safety is added in Dart. In simple words, Null Safety means a variable cannot contain a ‘null’ value unless you initialized with null to that variable. All the runtime null-dereference errors will now be shown in compile time with null safety.
So as you are initializing variables **serialNumber** & **productionDate** you have two options:

1. Either make it compulsory to provide those variables values from constructor by adding **required** keyword.

```
class SaveGlove{
    String serialNumber;

    final String productionDate;
    
    SaveGlove({required this.serialNumber, required this.productionDate});
    
}
```

2. Or declare those variables as nullable, i.e which can accept null values. So you don't need the **required** keyword:

```
    
class SaveGlove{
    String? serialNumber;
    String? productionDate;
        
    SaveGlove({this.serialNumber,this.productionDate});
}
```